# how can i restrict that image dont resize more than a particular limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Effect.scale property but the image goes on resizing without anylimit.

Suppose I remove the mouse from image in between the time image scales to full percentage specified and then again keep mouse cursor over there..... then again it grows much bigger.. similarly downscaling also too much.

How can I prevent it? Please help me out

```
<img src="test.gif" id="test"alt="Online Test portal"  style="position:absolute;top:935.5px;left:300px" title="online test portal" onmouseover= "new Effect.Scale('test', 150,{scaleX: true, scaleY: true}); return false;" onmouseout="new Effect.Scale('test', 66.67,{scaleX: true, scaleY: true}); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with pure css.

```
img { transition: all .2s linear; }
img:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using min-width, max-width properties?

On your element add:

```
style="position:absolute;top:935.5px;left:300px; max-width:100px"
```

100px or watever you think is reasonable

This will limit the width of the object to a predefined value.